# How to load large data set using volley

Tags: android, android-volley

How to use volley load data if I have a 1000 rows table?

This is the volley request I use currently but it only run request one time and fetch 10 rows. How to let volley request run 100 times to fetch all my data? For example, it fetch 1-10 rows first then start to fetch 11-20 rows after receive 1-10 rows and so on.

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, url,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String s) {

                    JSONObject obj;
                    try {
                        obj = new JSONObject(s);
                        if(obj.getInt(STATUS_CODE)==SUCCESS){
                            Log.d("logindatabase","success");
                            switch (objectType) {
                                case CATEGORY:
                                    loadList = loadCategory(obj);
                                    break;

                                default:
                                    break;
                            }
                            onCallBack.onSuccess(loadList);
                        }else{
                            Log.d("logindatabase","fail");
                            Toast.makeText(context, FAIL_MESSAGE , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Toast.makeText(context, FAIL_MESSAGE , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        onCallBack.onFail(e.toString());
                    }
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {

                    //Showing toast
                    Toast.makeText(context, volleyError.getMessage().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
            //Creating parameters
            Map<String,String> params;
            //Adding parameters
            switch (objectType) {
                case CATEGORY:
                    params = loadCategoryParameter();
                    break;

                default:
                    params = new Hashtable<String, String>();
                    break;
            }

            //returning parameters
            return params;
        }
    };

    //Creating a Request Queue
    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context.getApplicationContext());

    //Adding request to the queue
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is where paging comes into play. When you make a request provide which page do you want the data for as request parameter in Volley Request. First page = 1st to 10th row, second page = 11th to 20th row.

Also make sure your REST Api has the facility to query page on data.

Comment: But I will display all my data in recyclerview. So do you mean I need to do the trick at recycler view part? For example, I display 10 rows in recycle view then call this volley request again to fetch 11-20 rows

Comment: Yeah do not fetch all at once, use scroll listeners and  keep adding to adapter data once the next page is fetched through the volley